# CSS displaying div on :hover or :active of another div (that isnt within)

Tags: html, css, web, hover, nav

I have a nav bar going across the top of my page, on :active of a certain one, I would like a certain div on another part of the page to pop up, is this possible or does the div i want to pop up have to be within the nav bar div?

The first nav part is a nav bar going across the top of the page with. There are 4 buttons and a logo in the middle. The second section, that is within the wrapper div, uses the grid system to display three columns, in the first column is 'SubNavBar', second is 'Info' then third is 'Links'. There is a second nav bar, within the first column that I would like to appear when clicking on the first option from the top nav bar.

```
<nav class="container">

    <div class="1">
        <a href="#" class="navLinks1">Nav1</a>
    </div>

    <div class="2">
        <a href="#" class="navLinks2">Nav2</a>
    </div>

    <div class="logo"> Garrett Sauls
    </div>

    <div class="3">
        <a href="#" class="navLinks3">Nav3</a>
    </div>

    <div class="4">
        <a href="#" class="navLinks4">Nav4</a>
    </div>

</nav>

<div class="wrapper">

        <div class="one">SubNavBar

            <nav class = "container2">

                <div class="partOne">
                    <a href="#" class="navLinks2">Nav1.1</a>
                </div>

                <div class="partOne">
                    <a href="#" class="navLinks2">Nav1.2</a>
                </div>

                <div class="partOne">
                    <a href="#" class="navLinks2">Nav1.3</a>
                </div>

                <div class="partOne">
                    <a href="#" class="navLinks2">Nav1.4</a>
                </div>

            </nav>

        </div>

        <div class="two">Info



        </div>

        <div class="three">Links



        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: You should add more details. Maybe your HTMLstructure.

Comment: Just updated, apologies

Answer (score 1):

So you can do it, but it depends on the structure of your HTML.

If the element you want to apply the hover effect to is next to your div (adjacent), you can use the `+` adjacent selector.

If there are elements in between the two elements you want interacting, use the `~` general sibling selector:

```css
.first-element:hover + .adjacent-element {
    background: #9dff73;
}


.second-element:hover ~ .distant-element {
    background: #9dff73;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-element">Hover over me</div>
<div class="adjacent-element">Watch me light up!</div>

<br />

<div class="second-element">Hover over me</div>
<div>I'm a div</div>
<span>I'm a span</span>
<section>I'm a section</section>
<div class="distant-element">Watch me light up!</div>
```

Comment: Does it have to be a class from a div to work, or can it be a class from a <nav> tag?

Comment: I edited and posted the code above to hopefully give you a better idea. I tried your suggestion but I may be doing it wrong.